# custom setters in Intellij 12.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a class with some 20 properties. The setters should throw an exception if the property is not null. Something like below

```
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
 if(this.lastname!=null)
    throw new IlegalArgumentException("lastname already set");
 this.lastname=lastname;
}
```

How can I auto generate such setters in IntelliJ?

Comment: Sometimes, you have to type code by yourself. This is one of these situations. 40 lines shouldn't be too long to type, especially when you can copy-paste and replace.

Comment: This is not just for one class. I have several classes and our architect insists on writing setters in that format. If IDEA doesn't have a way to automate, I'll probably write a Python script to update the source files.

Comment: Aah, architects. The plague of software projects. It looks like you should use the builder pattern. I guess you could use a live template to please your architect. But that template will still have to be used for every setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a live template:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html

This should work like:

```
public void set$CAP_SELECTION$(String $SELECTION$) {
 if(this.$SELECTION$!=null)
    throw new IlegalArgumentException("$SELECTION$already set");
 this.$SELECTION$=$SELECTION$;
}
```

You just write:

lastname, select the test and use the template

CAP_SELECTION is a variable in kind of capitalize($SELECTION)

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA has no way to customize getter/setter templates, [vote for this request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-28206).

A workaround would be to create a [Surround live template](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html). This way you can type the variable, like `lastname`, then select it and invoke Surround template that will convert the selection into

```
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
 if(this.lastname!=null)
    throw new IlegalArgumentException("lastname already set");
 this.lastname=lastname;
}
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a template to generate setters which are generated with some customisation. My setter function first checks if the argument is not null and then only sets to the output. You can generate similar templates in intellij. While you are generating the setter click the [...] button and create a new custom template. Just for reference I am putting down my template gist link.

[Template for generating setter with checking not null in IntelliJ Idea](https://gist.github.com/rishibarve/9c830014d8313130700ca2f63671b3f6)